# Moodle Filtering courses based on a dropdown custom field

Tags: moodle

I have created some course custom fields and I want to create some to show some filters that will filter courses based on the user's preferences
e.g Filter Language has ENG, SP, IT

if user chooses ENG, it should displays only the courses that have ENG in language (custom field)

my code:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../config.php');

$PAGE->set_context(context_system::instance());
$PAGE->set_pagelayout('standard');
$PAGE->set_title("Custom Fields");
$PAGE->set_heading("All Custom Fields for Courses");

echo $OUTPUT->header();

$ftopics = $DB->get_records('customfield_field', array('shortname' => 'topic'));
$flevels = $DB->get_records('customfield_field', array('shortname' => 'level'));
$flanguages = $DB->get_records('customfield_field', array('shortname' => 'language'));

echo '<form method="get" action="#">'; // Start a form

// ----- TOPIC OPTIONS -----
echo '<select name="topic_filter" id="topic_filter">'; // Start a dropdown/select element
echo '<option value="">All Topics</option>'; // Include an option for all topics

foreach ($ftopics as $topic) {
    $configdata = json_decode($topic->configdata, true);

    // Check if 'options' key exists in the decoded configdata
    if (isset($configdata['options'])) {
        // Split the options string into an array using "\r\n" as the delimiter
        $options = explode("\r\n", $configdata['options']);

        // Remove empty values
        $options = array_filter($options);

        // Display options as dropdown options
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            echo '<option value="' . $option . '">' . $option . '</option>';
        }
    }
}

echo '</select>'; // End the dropdown/select element

// ----- LEVEL OPTIONS -----
echo '<select name="level_filter" id="level_filter">';
echo '<option value="">All Levels</option>'; // Include an option for all levels

foreach ($flevels as $level) {
    $configdata = json_decode($level->configdata, true);

    // Check if 'options' key exists in the decoded configdata
    if (isset($configdata['options'])) {
        // Split the options string into an array using "\r\n" as the delimiter
        $options = explode("\r\n", $configdata['options']);

        // Remove empty values
        $options = array_filter($options);

        // Display options as dropdown options
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            echo '<option value="' . $option . '">' . $option . '</option>';
        }
    }
}

echo '</select>'; // End the dropdown/select element

// ----- LANGUAGE OPTIONS -----
echo '<select name="language_filter" id="language_filter">';
echo '<option value="">All Languages</option>'; // Include an option for all languages

foreach ($flanguages as $language) {
    $configdata = json_decode($language->configdata, true);

    // Check if 'options' key exists in the decoded configdata
    if (isset($configdata['options'])) {
        // Split the options string into an array using "\r\n" as the delimiter
        $options = explode("\r\n", $configdata['options']);

        // Remove empty values
        $options = array_filter($options);

        // Display options as dropdown options
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            echo '<option value="' . $option . '">' . $option . '</option>';
        }
    }
}

echo '</select>'; // End the dropdown/select element

echo '<input type="submit" value="Filter">';
echo '</form>'; // End the form

// Fetch filter values
$topicFilter = optional_param('topic_filter', null, PARAM_TEXT);
$levelFilter = optional_param('level_filter', null, PARAM_TEXT);
$languageFilter = optional_param('language_filter', null, PARAM_TEXT);

// Construct SQL query based on the selected filters
$sql = "SELECT c.id, c.fullname, c.summary
        FROM {course} c";

// Add WHERE clause based on selected filters
$whereClause = array();
if (!empty($topicFilter)) {
    $whereClause[] = "c.id IN (SELECT cd.instanceid FROM {customfield_data} cd WHERE cd.shortname = 'topic' AND cd.value = :topic_filter AND cd.instanceid = c.id)";
}
if (!empty($levelFilter)) {
    $whereClause[] = "c.id IN (SELECT cd.instanceid FROM {customfield_data} cd WHERE cd.shortname = 'level' AND cd.value = :level_filter AND cd.instanceid = c.id)";
}
if (!empty($languageFilter)) {
    $whereClause[] = "c.id IN (SELECT cd.instanceid FROM {customfield_data} cd WHERE cd.shortname = 'language' AND cd.value = :language_filter AND cd.instanceid = c.id)";
}

// Combine WHERE clauses with AND
if (!empty($whereClause)) {
    $sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $whereClause);
}

// Execute the query
$params = array(
    'topic_filter' => $topicFilter,
    'level_filter' => $levelFilter,
    'language_filter' => $languageFilter
);

$courses = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, $params);

// Display the titles of the filtered courses
foreach ($courses as $course) {
    echo '<div>';
    echo '<h2>' . html_writer::link(new moodle_url('/course/view.php', array('id' => $course->id)), $course->fullname) . '</h2>';
    echo '<p>' . $course->summary . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}

echo $OUTPUT->footer();
?>
```

error:

Error reading from database

More information about this error

Debug info: Unknown column 'cd.shortname' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT c.id, c.fullname, c.summary
FROM mdl_course c WHERE c.id IN (SELECT cd.instanceid FROM mdl_customfield_data cd WHERE cd.shortname = 'level' AND cd.value = ? AND cd.instanceid = c.id)
[array (
0 => 'HEI',
)]
```

Error code: dmlreadexception

**Notes:**
Something that I was doing wrong I was using the option's result in the query. Eg language options had ENG, SP, IT and I was using in the query the string ENG to filter those courses.
WRONG use the id of the option.
Any other tips or suggestion, are more than welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `shortname` is in the `mdl_customfield_field` table

Use something like this

```
$sql = "SELECT c.id, c.fullname, c.summary
        FROM mdl_course c
        WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT cd.id
            FROM mdl_customfield_data cd
            JOIN mdl_customfield_field cf ON cf.id = cd.fieldid
            WHERE cd.instanceid = c.id
            AND (
                (cf.shortname = 'topic' AND cd.value = :topic)
                OR (cf.shortname = 'level' AND cd.value = :level)
                OR (cf.shortname = 'language' AND cd.value = :language)
            )
        )";
```

Also, the `EXISTS` operator is faster than using `IN`

Comment: @Thank Russel Awesome Query. Thanks for the tip too.
Just a note for someone else that tries to do something similar. In my case I had as I said a custom field with dropdown options. The big mistake was the inputing the option as string instead of the id of the option
cd.value = :xyzSomething , the right side needs to have the id of the option.